# Monotonity of an integral

Tags: real-analysis

It seems that for $p>4/3$ the following function  $$g(a)=\sec a\int_{-\pi}^\pi |\cos t|^p  (1 - \sin(a - t))^{3p-2}\sin tdt $$ achieves supremum when  $a\to \pi/2-0$ for  $a\in[0,\pi/2)$. How to prove this.

Comment: $\sec\pi/2=\infty,$ therefore $g(\pi/2-0)=+\infty$ and finite at all other points, therefore $\pi/2$ is the unique maximum on $[0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: "monotonity"?  I prefer; "monotony" or "monotonicity".

Comment: for $p=2$ the integral can be evaluated and $g(a)=\frac{1}{2} \pi  (4-\cos 2 a)$ --- with a finite maximum at $a=\pi/2$.

Comment: I find the language confusing—the supremum on a set $[0, \pi/2)$ is achieved at a point $a = \pi/2$ outside the set?

Comment: Ask it at MSE which is a right forum for such type questions.